# In or on connected with contract meal booking

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I am in a plight of choosing preposition between *in* and *on*. I have several instances as follows:

- Will free texts be included **in/on** the phone contract (plan)?
- What am I going to get **in/on** this meal?
- How many nights are there **on/in** this booking?

Comment: Hmm... I would rather use "with". You might consider it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes more than one preposition can work. For your first two examples, I would probably use **with**:

> Will free texts be included **with** the phone contract (plan)?
>
> What am I going to get **with** this meal?

That said, I think ***in** the phone plan* sounds just fine.

Also, either *on* or *in* sound acceptable to me for your third sentence, but I'd be more likely to use *on*.